Setting useRefs dynamically react, typescript
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export default function test() {
  const divs = [1, 2, 3];
  const refs = useRef<(HTMLDivElement | null)[]>([]);
  return (
    <>
      {divs.map((v, i) => {
        <div ref={(el) => (refs.current[i] = el)}>test</div>;
      })}
    </>
  );
}

i want to do a preloader animation with the divs via the refs. Gives me a ts error when trying to assign refs to the dynamic elements:
Type '(el: HTMLDivElement | null) => HTMLDivElement | null' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement> | undefined'.
  Type '(el: HTMLDivElement | null) => HTMLDivElement | null' is not assignable to type '(instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void | (() => VoidOrUndefinedOnly)'.
    Type 'HTMLDivElement | null' is not assignable to type 'void | (() => VoidOrUndefinedOnly)'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'void | (() => VoidOrUndefinedOnly)'.ts(2322)



Quick question, what is your use case in particular here? Instead of creating a ref for each div, you could create only one for the wrapper and access the children divs programmatically when needed.

i want to do a preloader animation with the divs via the refs. if not that would totally work!

I think your best bet in this case is to just have a ref provided to a parent and just access the child divs with ref.current.children. Keeping track of multiple refs like this is not necessary and could give issues if for some reason divs were to change.

Thanks moonstar! that worked really well!

an assignment statement returns the value that was assigned
And the ref function shouldn't return anything:
<div ref={(el) => {refs.current[i] = el}}>test</div>

